# Concatenating strings with log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

Is it possible to do something like this with log4net logging ?

```
logger.Debug("username : {0} password : {1} server : {2}",username,server,password)
```

Or am i only left with the option of ugly `"+"` concatenating.

Comment: If it's not supported, you can always fall back on `string.Format`. +1 for wanting to avoid concatenation.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can, in two ways

```
log.Debug(String.format("username : {0} password : {1} server : {2}",username,server,password));
```

Or use [default API](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_ILog_DebugFormat_4.htm)

```
logger.DebugFormat("username : {0} password : {1} server : {2}",username,server,password)
```

Comment: Note that DebugFormat will *avoid* the CPU cost of doing any string operations or `ToString()` calls if the current loglevel is Info or higher. All the the other string formatting answers don't have this optimization.

Comment: Not exactly. Yes, the very first line of `DebugFormat` method checks the logging level, and may return if lower. But .NET will always evaluate **all** the expressions you pass as arguments before calling the method. In the example above I am passing only object references so that's fine. But what if for a reason I call `log.DebugFormat()` passing, along the arguments, an expression that is heavy to evaluate like a database query? Yes it's a bad idea but just to highlight that if the `ToString()` operation is evaluated at String format level the comment is correct, otherwise not

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the new [string interpolation feature of C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#string-interpolation):

```
logger.Debug($"username : {username} password : {password} server : {server}")
```

Comment: It's going to take a while before my eyes stop bleeding on this, but ultimately it's probably the best answer!

Comment: This is a poor example, but I've used in some of my project where we had long string and find it was easier to read than having to find which variable correspond to which placeholder. Having this is option is a plus for me and Visual Studio does a better formating than SO.

Comment: The caveat of calling `Debug` instead of using `DebugFormat` is that calling `Debug` will always result in the string being evaluated even if the log level is higher. When calling `DebugFormat` the string will only be evaluated if the log level is low enough. So in applications where performance is a concern, you may want to consider using `DebugFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string format like this :

```
logger.Debug(string.Format("username : {0} password : {1} server : {2}", 
                           username, server, password))
```